# Телеграм бот на heroku перестал работать со странной ошибкой

Tags: python, flask, heroku, telepot

Есть телеграм бот, написанный на python с библиотекой telepot. Я его заливаю на heroku. Раньше всё работало, но вот в очередной раз я его обновил и он выдаёт мне вот такую ошибку:

telepot.exception.TelegramError: ('Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running', 409, {'ok': False, 'error_code': 409, 'description': 'Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running'})

У меня нигде больше не запущен этот бот. Более того, всё работает без проблем когда я запускаю heroku local или просто flask run. А на heroku не работает. Пожалуйста, подскажите в чём может быть проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что моё приложение на heroku запускает 2 процесса (так называемых worker). А локально запускается 1. Вот в этом вопросе я выкладывал логи:
[heroku запускает 2 worker-а вместо 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/977514/heroku-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-2-worker-%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-1)

Решение обнаружилось, когда я запустил heroku run bash и смотрел переменные окружение командой env. Мне показалась интересной переменная WEB_CONCURRENCY=2. После того, как я в настройках приложения установил её равной 1, всё заработало как нужно.

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ решением, это облегчит его поиск для других пользователей, у которых возникнет такая же проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, у Вас уже запущен вэбхук с другого урла или вы используете GetUpdates где-то в другом месте.
Попробуйте в коде самого бота указать сначала удалить старый вэбхук, и только после этого устанавливать его снова.
Мне в свое время помогло именно это

Comment: Я вообще не использую вебхук. И getUpdates нигде больше не запущен. Сейчас попробовал в коде прописать deleteWebhook на всякий случай - не помогло.